# Do ganga water only clean sins of human or also of animals, plants and micro -organisms?

Tags: sin, animals, ganga, plants

Do ganga water only clean sins of human or also of animals, plants and micro -organisms?

Please also explain in answer that sins are only cleared for one birth or previous births also.

Comment: From the perspective of advaita, only jnAna can destroy karmas (including sins). Ganga water etc. can aid in developing chitta suddhi. This can indirectly, but not directly, lead to destruction of sins.

Comment: Animals, plants and micro-organisms are not morally aware and are not judged by their karma. Sin applies only to humans.